# Circles on svg wont tween correctly using D3 javascript library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tween

I currently am using the D3 library to create a donut chart. I have two states for the chart that you tween between when a button is pushed. The pie slices, poly lines, and text labels all tween correctly around the chart when the button is pushed. However some circles I have do not tween correctly when I press the button. The circles remain in place however new circles are drawn in the ending location of the transform.

I have a jsfiddle that shows the behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7847/

The code in question that controls the circles is specifically here:

```
        /* ------- OUTER POINTS -------*/


        var outerPoint = fndAfter.select(".outerPoints").selectAll(".outerPoint")
           .data(pie(data), key);

        outerPoint.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", "2");

        outerPoint.transition().duration(1000)
            .attrTween("transform", function (d) {
                this._current = this._current || d;
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                this._current = interpolate(0);
                return function (t) {

                    var d2 = interpolate(t);
                    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                    pos[0] = radius * 0.624 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
                };
            });

        outerPoint.exit()
            .remove();

        /* ------- INNER POINTS -------*/

        var innerPoint = fndAfter.select(".innerPoints").selectAll(".innerPoint")
           .data(pie(data), key);

        innerPoint.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", "2");

        innerPoint.transition().duration(1000)
            .attrTween("transform", function (d) {
                this._current = this._current || d;
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                this._current = interpolate(0);
                return function (t) {
                    var d2 = interpolate(t);
                    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                    pos[0] = radius * 0.624 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return "translate(" + midPoint(midPoint(arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2)), outerArc.centroid(d2)) + ")";
                };
            });

        innerPoint.exit()
            .remove();
```

I was under the impression that the attrTween should work the same for all transform functions no matter what element it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with attrTween. You use `selectAll('.innerPoint')` to define your selection, but you never apply the `innerPoint` class to the circles, so d3 never finds any matching selection and appends new circles every time.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7849/